# Django-allauth Как получить данные из поля extra_data пользователя?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Сделал авторизацию на сайте через Steam. Подскажите пожалуйста, как получать данные из поля extra_data, что бы, например, выводить на страницу имя пользователя, его аватар и тд.
[image: extra_data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модель из `allauth` - `SocialAccount`.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

def get_extra_data(user, provider):
    if not user or not provider:
        return None

    try:
        social_account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user, provider=provider)
    except SocialAccount.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    else:
        return social_account.extra_data
```

Нужно передать юзера и провайдера, вернет либо `None`, либо данные.